# Why static fields initialization occurs before the static constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, static

The following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("0");
    string h = Foo.X;
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}

public static class Foo
{
    public static string X = ((Func<string, string>)delegate(string g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(g);
        return (g);
    })("_aaa");

    static Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor");
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
0
_aaa
ctor
2
```

I know about the `beforefieldinit` behavior (with/without static constructor etc.).

The thing which I *don't* understand is why the `ctor` (in the output) is *after* `_aaa`?

It doesn't make any sense, what if I want to initialize variables in the constructor?

**Question**

Why does the initialization of `X` is before the `ctor`?

Comment: It is similar for non-static fields and non-static constructors, of course: `class Foo { public string X = "A"; public Foo() { X = "B"; } }` With this, if you do `(new Foo()).X`, you get `"B"`, not `"A"`, because the assignment of `"B"` happened last (overwrote the first value).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason `ctor` is after the field initializers is because that's the way it is specified. From the C# specification (emphasis is mine):

> 10.5.5.1 Static field initialization The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that
>   are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class
>   declaration. **If a static constructor (§10.12) exists in the class,
>   execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to
>   executing that static constructor.** Otherwise, the static field
>   initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to
>   the first use of a static field of that class

If you want to have total control of your initialization order, move it all inside the constructor.