# Do both of these constructors do the same thing?

Tags: c#, static-constructor

Do both of these code blocks do the same thing?

```
class A {
   public static int s;
   A(){}
   static A(){s = 100;}
}
```

and

```
class A {
   public static int s=100;
   A(){}
   //static A(){s = 100;} do not use
}
```

Do they do the same thing? I think so.

Comment: Both instances of `s` will be 100, yes.

Comment: In this case they will produce the same result after the fact, they'll simply do it in different ways.

Comment: Please try to use the search and share what you have found. Everything the answers here repeat had been explained before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285168/why-static-fields-initialization-occurs-before-the-static-constructor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761393/static-readonly-field-initializer-vs-static-constructor-initialization

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they don't behave quite the same way. Without the static constructor, the timing of exactly when the type initializer executes is much looser - it can happen earlier *or later* than you'd expect.

When there's a static constructor, the type initializer executes when the type is first used in terms of any static member being accessed or any instance being created.

When there *isn't* a static constructor, the only guarantee is that the initializer will be executed at some point before the first access of a static field (and still exactly once). Depending on the JIT, that might mean it's executed very early (e.g. when you first execute a method which *might* use a member) or very late (*after* calling static members which don't use any fields, or after creating and using an instance).

In IL, the difference is that a type without a static constructor has the [`beforefieldinit`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) flag; one with a static constructor doesn't.

Comment: When both options are possible, which one do you usually prefer, with or without the static constructor definition?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Usually I go with whichever's clearer - which is *typically* without a static constructor unless I'm doing significant work in initialization (which is usually a design smell anyway).

Answer (score 4):

The *effect* is the same, but the actual order of execution may be different.  When there is a static constructor, static fields are initialized immediately before the constructor is called or any of the static fields are accessed.  If there is no static constructor, then the field initializers can be executed *at any time prior to the first usage of one of the static fields*.

Since your initializers have no side-effects and cannot throw exceptions, there would not be any discernable difference in the two, barring the use of reflection or some other outside observer (e.g. debugger)

Comment: Not quite: when there's a static constructor, it's immediately before the constructor is called or any static member. When there isn't a static constructor, it's before any access to a *static* field - using an instance field doesn't have to trigger the initializer.

Answer (score 3):

Except for some edge cases such as [`beforefieldinit`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) behavior, **yes, they do the same thing**. In fact, the compiled IL is nearly the same in the two cases. The only difference is the presence of `beforefieldinit` on the one without a static constructor.

```
class A
{
    public static int s;
    A() { }
    static A() { s = 100; }
}

class B
{
    public static int s = 100;
    B() { }
}
```

Compiles to...

```
.class private auto ansi A
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit B
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
```

With identical method/field definitions.

Answer (score 0):

According to *C# in a Nutshell* the static constructor is executed when you first use of the property, and the most usage of this is when you want to calculate or read some data and set to the static property *(Like a password from appconfig.config)*. without using the static constructor you must define a Init method and call it when your application has been started.