# Static constructor does not seem to be called?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have the following piece of code：

```
// using Windows.Storage;
internal static class AppData {
    private static ApplicationDataContainer container;
    public static bool FirstTime { get; } = !GetContainer("UserInfo").Values.ContainsKey("complete");
    static AppData() {
        container = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    }
    private static ApplicationDataContainer GetContainer(string name) {
        return container.CreateContainer(name,ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
    }
}
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I don't know why it's wrong. Make some changes to the code

```
// using Windows.Storage;
internal static class AppData {
    private static ApplicationDataContainer container;
    public static bool FirstTime => !GetContainer("UserInfo").Values.ContainsKey("complete");
    static AppData() {
        container = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    }
    private static ApplicationDataContainer GetContainer(string name) {
        return container.CreateContainer(name,ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
    }
}
```

> OK, No error.

Why?

Comment: Did you check if 
ApplicationData is null or ApplicationData.Current is null ?

Comment: This is not really a null reference question.  In the first code chunk you have a property initializer, in the second you have a function definition.

Comment: The first version sets up a read-only property (with backing field) and assigns to the backing field at static construction time. The second sets up a property (with just a getter) _without a backing field_. The second will work because, by the time you call it, `container` won't be `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why static fields initialization occurs before the static constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285168/why-static-fields-initialization-occurs-before-the-static-constructor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll have to look up [the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285210/5311735) but the issue is that

```
public static bool FirstTime { get; } = ....;
```

is an initializer. And as an initializer it is executed just before the constructor.

When you change it to a function (or readonly lambda property), it is a normal member and it gets executed after the constructor.

Comment: Here is that reference to save you lookup time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285210/5311735

Comment: I second @mjwills. "=>" will make a read-only Prop without backing field, won't it?

Comment: @Fildor it's a read-only property indeed. But read-only property is basically one function (like `GetFirstTime`), so distinction doesn't matter for this quesion. Still it's property and will be for example returned by `Type.GetProperty("FirstTime")`.

Comment: But you're right about the property, it is `bool FirstIme => ...` and a method would look like `bool FirstIme() => ...`.  Semantics are the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is a big difference in the two syntaxes:

```
public static bool Property { get; set; } = true;
```

This is a property initialization syntax and is evaluated before any constructor runs. The property can have a setter as well here.

```
public static bool Property => true;
```

This is an expression property, get-only and the right hand side is evaluated only when it is called. This also means that it is evaluated each time it is accessed, so it is not a good design choice to use a complex method call on the right-hand side for example.

Also if you want to have the expression syntax while ensuring the right-hand side will be evaluated only when actually needed and only once, you can combine this syntax with a private field:

```
private static bool? _property;

public static bool Property => _property ?? ( _property = CalculateProperty() );
```

This will first check if the private backing field is `null` and if yes, initialize it, while the assignment itself will then return the assigned value as well.